# Resolving dependencies in a Func<T> that is moved to a separate class file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, func, minimal-apis

I'm working with a codebase (**Minimal APIs : .NET 6**) which exposes a custom middleware (`UseCustomMiddleware`) that is added to `IApplicationBuilder` via extension methods.

The second parameter of `UseCustomMiddleware` is a `Func<HttpRequest, Identity, Message, ... Task<(bool Pass, Error Error)>` that act as a predicate for providing authentication mechanism.

Here's the layout in **Program.cs**:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationService>();

var app = builder.Build();
    
app.UseCustomMiddleware<IContract,Methods>("/", async (httpRequest, accessibility, message, ...) =>
{
    //resolving dependencies here is not a problem.
    var authenticationService = app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationService>();
    //the rest of logic continues...
});
```

Everything works fine but the logic inside lambda is getting lengthier and lengthier and I need to move that to a separate class file.

I could create a static class and define the same static method with the signature of `Func<...>` and reference it in place of lambda but then I don't know how to resolve dependencies in there.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no single "proper" way to achieve this. My advice would be to try different refactorings and see what suits you best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what `UseCustomMiddleware` is but you don't need `app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider...` (also you don't dispose the scope which is bad). Middleware should have access to `HttpContext`, which has `RequestServices` property which you should use to resolve services. In theory you can try to get it from `HttpRequest`:

```cs
app.UseCustomMiddleware<IContract,Methods>("/", async (httpRequest, accessibility, message, ...) =>
{
    var authenticationService = httpRequest.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationService>();
});
```

Also see samples in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0), especially for middlewares extracted into classes, I would argue they are more suitable for complex logic then ones with `Func` handlers.

Comment: Resolving dependencies via `HttpContext` was a nice trick! Thanks. That solves the problem.

Comment: By the way, just out of curiosity, do you think is there anyway to resolve dependencies if `HttpContext` was not available?

Comment: @wiki was glad to help! As for the question - it is to broad. If we are talking about middleware only then I would argue that it does not have much sense, cause it should be available cause we use middleware pipeline to handle http requests (i.e. no context - no middleware needed).